# Difficulty with pd.read_csv in pandas - Unexpected Tokenizing Error

Tags: python, pandas, version

I'm encountering an issue while trying to read a CSV file using the pandas library in Python. I've used the pd.read_csv function, but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out.

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

The error I'm getting is: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 7, saw 6.

I've double-checked the CSV file to ensure it has the correct number of columns. I also searched online for similar issues but couldn't find a solution that worked for my case.

I expected the pd.read_csv function to successfully read the CSV file into a DataFrame. However, I'm encountering the mentioned error, and the DataFrame is not being created.

Comment: Could you provide the data including line 7?

Comment: Does line 7 end in a comma by chance? Does it have a text column that contains a comma? Perhaps you are just missing the proper separator definition. If we saw the first 10 lines of the file in question it would probably be easy to suggest a fix.

Comment: Somehow when parsing line 7, it finds an extra cell. There is a comma missing, or one too many. Cannot say more without seeing the line. You've taken the tour, now see [mre] and [ask] for guidance to increase your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the read_csv to:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

This will skip lines which have not enough or too many columns